# PHP Increment a counting variable in a text file

Tags: php

This seems simple but I can't figure it out.

```
file_get_contents('count.txt');
$variable_from_file++;
file_put_contents('count.txt', $variable_from_file);
```

There is only one line of data in `count.txt` and it is the hits counter. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$variable_from_file = (int)file_get_contents('count.txt');
```

But notice that this is not thread-safe.

Comment: In the simplest terms, when `file_get_contents()` is reading the file, no other threads (programs) can until it's completely done. [Read more about safe-threading here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx).

Comment: This is 100% thread safe. Unless `$variable_from_file` is a global variable modifiable from multiple threads. Which given the current code is not.

Comment: @Cristik the terminology was off. I didn't mean thread safe. See ian's answer below.

Answer (score 15):

If you want to be sure no increments go uncounted (which is what CodeCaster is referring to, the script may load `count.txt`, increment it, while another file is doing the same, then save that, and then only one increment would have been done and not the proper two), you should use `fopen`.

```php
$filename = "count.txt";

$count = 0;

$fp = fopen( $filename, 'c+' );
flock( $fp, LOCK_EX );
$size = filesize( $filename );

if( $size > 0 ) { 
  // Coerce to largest natural data type.
  $count = fread( $fp, $size ) + 0;

  ftruncate( $fp, 0 );
  fseek( $fp, 0 );
} 

fwrite( $fp, $count + 1 );

flock( $fp, LOCK_UN );
fclose( $fp );
```

This will lock the file, preventing any others from reading or writing to it while the count is incremented (meaning others would have to wait before they can increment the value).

Comment: Yes it will count all requests, but it will lock all of them, too. This means this code is a bottleneck and is not recommened. Its not really easy to count every request AND avoid blocking multiple threads.

Answer (score 5):

There is a slightly funnier way:

```
file_put_contents("count.txt",@file_get_contents("count.txt")+1);
```

**file_get_contents** reads the contents of the counter file.

**@** tells PHP to ignore the error of a missing file. The returned false will then be interpreted as the count of 0.

+1 will cause the string to be converted to a number.

**file_put_contents** then stores the new value in the counter file as a string.

On a very busy system you might want to obtain a file lock first to prevent simultaneous writes.
The OS file cache usually makes this method extremely fast.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly like you did it should work fine. Just capture the data from `file_get_contents()`, and check if both of those functions were successful.

```
$var = file_get_contents('count.txt');
if ($var === false) {
    die('Some error message.');
}
$var++;
if (file_put_contents('count.txt', $var) === false) {
    die('Some error message.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me though

```
$count = intval(file_get_contents('count.txt'));
file_put_contents('count.txt', ++$count);
echo file_get_contents('count.txt');
```