# Obtain exclusive read/write lock on a file for atomic updates

Tags: php, locking

I want to have a PHP file that is used as a counter. It will a) echo the current value of a txt file, and b) increment that file using an exclusive lock so no other scripts can read or write to it while it's being used.

User A will write and increment this number, while User B requests to read the file. Is it possible that User A can lock this file so no one can read or write to it until User A's write is finished?

I've used `flock` in the past, but I'm not sure how to get the file to wait until it is available, rather than quitting if it's already been locked

My goal is:

```
LOCK counter.txt; write to counter.txt;
```

while at the same time

```
Read counter.txt; realize it's locked so wait until that lock is finished.
```

//

```
$fp = fopen("counter.txt", 'w+');
if(flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    fwrite($fp, $counter + 1);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
} else {
    // try again??
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: There's a 3rd argument for flock() that specifies blocking behavior: http://php.net/flock. But by default is WILL block until the lock is acquired, which is also mentioned in the same docs.

Comment: In the case where this is used, would other scripts wait until it is no longer locked? There's not much detail in the doc page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Increment a counting variable in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874950/php-increment-a-counting-variable-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 4):

From documentation: [By default, this function will block until the requested lock is acquired](http://php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php)

So simply use flock in your reader (LOCK_SH) and writer (LOCK_EX), and it is going to work.
However I highly discourage use of blocking flock without timeout as this means that if something goes wrong then your program is going to hang forever. To avoid this use non-blocking request like this (again, it is in doc):

```
/* Activate the LOCK_NB option on an LOCK_EX operation */
if(!flock($fp, LOCK_EX | LOCK_NB)) {
    echo 'Unable to obtain lock';
}
```

And wrap it in a for loop, with sleep and break after failed n-tries (or total wait time).

EDIT: You can also look for some examples of usage [here](https://github.com/arvenil/ninja-mutex/blob/master/src/NinjaMutex/Lock/FlockLock.php). This class is a part of [ninja-mutex](https://github.com/arvenil/ninja-mutex) library in which you may be interested too.