# Maximum connections to json file via php

Tags: php, json

I'm searching on web for last 6 months for this. I have php aplication that uses json object stored in json file .Does anyone know what maximum number of connections to that file is ? That file will be updated many times at same moment so i have fear that something may go wrong there . Is there some way to stall process of updating if one progress is not done or something similar ? tnx in advance

Comment: maybe interesting? [Forget flock() and System V Semaphores - use WebMutex instead](http://cubicspot.blogspot.co.uk/2010/10/forget-flock-and-system-v-semaphores.html) Also: [Obtain exclusive read/write lock on a file for atomic updates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20829422/obtain-exclusive-read-write-lock-on-a-file-for-atomic-updates).

Answer (score 0):

You can lock the file while updating and check for a lock before trying to update.

```
$fp = fopen("foo.txt", "w");
if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
    fwrite($file,"Write something");
    sleep(10);
    flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
}
```

If you want to retry you could use `do` with `try, catch`

```
$attempts = 5;
$i = 0;
do {
    try
    {
        yourFunction();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $i++;
        sleep(1);
        continue;
    }
    break;
} while($i< $attempts);

function yourFunction() {
    $fp = fopen("foo.txt", "w");
    if (flock($fp, LOCK_EX)) {
        fwrite($file,"Write something");
        sleep(10);
        flock($fp, LOCK_UN);
    }
}
```