# How to read and write to a file, ensuring file is locked?

Tags: php, fopen, atomic, flock

I am looking to numerically increment to a file's content if the file was last modified within 24 hours otherwise reset the file's content to 1. However I want to ensure this continues to work regardless of how many users visit the script at the same time (the script would always need to execute but ensure it does not overwrite/calculate incorrectly - I believe this is where flock comes to use).

Please see below code:

```
$host_limit = 50;
$file = 'timer.txt';
$fh = fopen($file,'r+');
if (flock($fh,LOCK_EX)) {
$content = fgets($fh);
//FILE HAS NOT BEEN MODIFIED IN LAST 24 HOURS
if (strtotime('-24 hours') > filemtime($file)) {
$content = 1;
} else {
$content = ($content + 1);
}
fwrite($fh, $content);
fflush($fh);
flock($fh,LOCK_UN);
}
fclose($fh);

if ($content < $host_limit) {
//do stuff
}
```

Would the above work as I would like (as have no way to simulate what I am anticipating to test)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP Increment a counting variable in a text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874950/php-increment-a-counting-variable-in-a-text-file)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using fopen and fwrite, you could use
file_get_contents($file);
and
file_put_contents($file, $content, LOCK_EX);

Check the manual:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Wouldn't there be a risk in using file_get_contents on $content as that does not support the LOCK_EX, so might actually contain outdated file content? also does the file_put_contents with LOCK_EX wait until any previous lock is unlocked before executing or will it just fail in that instance?

Comment: Sorry, I probably misunderstood.. You could mix it up with the above file_get_contents and file_put_contents though.. Other than that, try your luck.. It doesnt look too far off, but almost impossible to do a stress test on your own.. Maybe put some data in a log file, and test it for a couple of days

Comment: file_get_contents() is not atomic as it does not respect advisory locks.

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work for me. I'll occasionally get empty string reads from file_get_contents despite using LOCK_EX on the file_put_contents