# is there a better way to do this? fopen, fread, fwrite

Tags: php

is there a better way to do this:

```
$countfile = fopen("count.txt", 'r');
$read = fread($ebf, filesize("count.txt")); 
$ebn = $read+1;
fclose($ebf);
$ebf = fopen($ebc, 'w');
fwrite($ebf, $ebn);
```

I wrote this script for counting the visits

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874950/php-increment-a-counting-variable-in-a-text-file

Comment: What do you mean by "better"? You could use `file_get_contents` and `file_put_contents`..

Comment: Absolutely .. This needs to be stored in a MySQL database ...  What happens when two users show up at the same exact moment and the file is open by one and needs to be written by the other?  Inaccurate ..  Use a database!

Comment: A database would be my "better" view of the solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same results via [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
$read = file_get_contents("count.txt");
$ebn = $read+1;
file_put_contents($ebc, $ebn);
```